# Z-index and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to z-index different "containers" in bootstrap in order for them to be placed on top of each.

I've classed the different containers and provided them different z-index positions. Nothing happens.

Here is the code and the css

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Bootstrap test</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css"></link>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-7 col">
                <h1>fælælflflflflf</h1>
                <p>
                    fkgkfklgkmnøblingbngæbkbjngækjndfælgkbjnfdækgjngfæbkjngfæbf gbkjnlfdkgbjngflkbjngfækbjnglkbnblkgjnblkgjbngflkbjgflkbjfkl
                    gfnæbæklkgjnbdkæjnblkjfdnblkdjngfkjbnlkjbnkgbjldkbjngklbjnkgjn
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container behind">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-7 col">
                <h1>fælælflflflflf</h1>
                <p>
                    fkgkfklgkmnøblingbngæbkbjngækjndfælgkbjnfdækgjngfæbkjngfæbf gbkjnlfdkgbjngflkbjngfækbjnglkbnblkgjnblkgjbngflkbjgflkbjfkl
                    gfnæbæklkgjnbdkæjnblkjfdnblkdjngfkjbnlkjbnkgbjldkbjngklbjnkgjn
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: trebuchet ms;
    color:#666666; }

.container {
    z-index: 1;
}

.col {
    margin:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow:20px 20px 10px #0033cc;
}

.behind {
    padding-bottom:40px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Note: i've added some padding in order to see containers layered on top of each other.

Thanks for your reply

Comment: z-index doesn't work in position static elements.

Comment: z-index only works on positioned items

Comment: Thanks for your reply:-) I've been reading up on positioning now.